# Ubuntu and Epson C67

Tags: printing

I have a PC with Windows 8 and a printer Epson C67. The driver is outdated for Windows 8. I want to know if is possible to use the printer with Ubuntu and what I have to do.

Comment: Somehow I believe you wrote windows where you should have written Ubuntu. You probably need gutenprint for Stylus ( http://gimp-print.sourceforge.net/ )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use that printer with Ubuntu. Chances are that the printer will be recognized out-of-the-box and the necessary drivers will be installed automatically. If not then you can download the drivers from http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/ (type C67 in the product name field and choose Linux operating system) to install them manually.